# View sp list item attachment high CPU usage server restart needed SP 2010 EBS

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, attachments

We are using SP 2010 with EBS (external blob storage [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802812(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802812%28v=office.14%29.aspx)).

The problem: When a user tries to download some large attachments (100MB) from a SharePoint list item, the CPU usage runs high and a restart of the w3wp process is needed. How can we solve the problem?

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party provider or did you create your own?

Comment: Also, what does your farm topology look like? Maybe your current setup is too weak to be hosting 100mb files.

Comment: Did you checked if you Antivirus isn't causing this?

Answer (score 1):

In general you should't be storing documents of big size in SharePoint. A better approach would be to store it on a file share or FTP and simply link to the file from SharePoint.

You technically cannot store a file larger than 2 GB (2047 MB) to SharePoint. This is the maximum size. If you want to allow files up to 2 GB you'll need to increase the connection time-out in IIS and increase the maximum upload size for the web application.

1.SharePoint limit's the upload to 2GB due to IIS's worker process w3wp.exe, to upload a file you need to use all the IIS available memory to upload the full stream. Each w3wp.exe worker process runs well with 2-4GB of memory, this is not a boundary just a good idea (on x64), therefore this makes sense to me that the SP2010 team have limited any file upload to 2GB. If you start to download the file , your site would be very slow because all the IIS process is used for downlaoding the large documents.

2.Also be aware that increasing you upload file size to 2 GB has performance ramifications so it a user uploads a file and there is no memory available no new requests can be handled until the memory is available again.

I am sure there will be performance sure with huge GB of data.

Answer (score 0):

As Jay Doshi stated, it is not wise to store big files in Sharepoint. Better is to save these to one of your network drives and link to them from your library. Also i think because your files are big, the IIS Worker Process is getting "saturated" and probably overflows. You can assign more cpu usage to rule out if this is the problem, but i wouldn't suggest you to keep it that way.

My suggestion is that you look at the way how you are storing files in your company.